# Инициализация переменных конструктором значениями из файла в java

Tags: java

Не могли бы подсказать каким образом при создании объекта инициализировать переменные этого объекта конструктором значениями из текстового файла и каким образом грамотно расположить текстовой файл в проекте?
Есть 2 класса: 1-й с методом main; 2-й тот класс объект которого будем создавать и есть один файл data.txt со значениями:
Nikolay
Ivanov
24

Классы:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User(); // значения из файла data
    }
}

public class User {
    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, String secondName, int age ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: файл обычно кладут в `resources`. Т.е. есть: `src/main/java` и `src/main/resources`. Далее файл можно считатеть через `getClass().getResource` или `getClass().getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Для текстового файла важно определить формат данных. Без знания формата содержимое использовать невозможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кладете файл в resources. В методе main читаете данные из файла. Потом вызываете конструктор класса User. Например так:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = ... 

        User user = buildUser( readData(filePath) ) // значения из файла data
    }

    private static User buildUser(String data){
        //data = "Nikolay Ivanov 24"
        String[] arr = data.split(" ");
        return new User(arr[0], arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]) )
    }

    private static String readData(String filePath){

        String data = null;  

        try( FileReader inputStream = new FileReader( filePath);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( inputStream )){
            data = reader.readLine();
        }catch( IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    } 
}


public class User {
    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, String secondName, int age ) {
       this.name = name;
       this.secondName = secondName;
       this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: думаю, не помешает указать кодировку при считывании. И если файл в resources, то проще доставать через `getResource` -- особенно, если проект будет перемещаться, или если будет запускаться на другом ПК

Comment: Благодарю. Очень помогли! Небольшой вопрос еще. Как было бы правильно разместить данные методы? Оставить их в Test или может организовать в один класс. Как думаете?